# how can I build a website with dynamic menu depending a profile?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I want to create a website using user profiles and build the menu dynamically depending of the profile selected, eg if I need an administrator user that the menu contains all the permissions without restrictions, if a seller is required I need to build the menu depending of tasks that the seller can do, such as catalogs, prices, etc.

I am currently doing a menu for each user, that is, doing one called administrator and another called seller, when someone log in, the profile should be verified eg if the log in user is an administrator the administrator menu is loaded, and if it is seller charge the seller menu, but  I don’t want to do it that way because there may be more than 20 roles and need to optimize, I would appreciate to have some help, I’m using html5, php, javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a q&a community. We are happy to help with specific problems, but not with general broad advice. Please show some code you have written already, and explain where you hare having trouble. See [ask] if you need help on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is probably better off being in PHP rather than JavaScript. Of course the menu movement stuff would be in JavaScript, but I don't think that's what you're asking about (it should probably be its own question if you need help with that as well).

For the menus, instead of building each menu, flip it around. For each possible item, define which roles can see that item. Then, go through each item, pulling out the ones that match the user's given role.

This code is kind of generic since I have no clue what your working with, but:

```
class MenuItem {
    public $name;
    public $url;
    public $allowedRoles;

    public function __construct($name, $url, $allowedRoles) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->allowedRoles = $allowedRoles;
    }
}

$items = array(
   new MenuItem('Everyone', 'http://example.com', array('seller', 'admin')),
   new MenuItem('Sellers Only', 'http://example.com/seller', array('seller')),
   new MenuItem('Admins Only', 'http://example.com/admin', array('admin'))
);

function getItemsForRole($items, $role) {
   $userItems = array();

   foreach ($items as $item) {
      if (in_array($role, $item->allowedRoles) {
          $userItems[] = $item;
      }
   }

   return $userItems;
}

$adminItems = getItemsForRole($items, 'admin');
$sellerItems = getItemsForRole($items, 'seller');
```

You'd still need the logic for the user and build the appropriate menu, but hopefully that gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a few ways.

1. Have an include file for each type, although with 20 profiles that could get to be a lot of files.
2. Depending on the structure of your menu, use a multidimensional array with your user type as the key and the value of each item to be a second array with all menu items.. Then use php to move through the array.
3. You could do your array the other way, and have your full menu and then only show parts depending on which users are assigned to it based of settings in your array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good application for [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) - create a user viewmodel with with a type, and then use `data-bind="with: User, visible: User.Type()=='Admin' || User.Type() == 'Sales'"` as an HTML attribute to hide/show your menu items automatically.

Of course, to be secure you will still have to check that the user has the right access level to perform a given action, but that's a relatively straightforward process.